# Ford Explorer overheating

Tags: ford, cooling-system

2003 ford exp xlt overheating. replaced t-stat and dumped & refilled coolant. Still over heating bad when on the highway at about 65 mph.

Answer (score 1):

Overheating problems can be difficult to pinpoint in older vehicles since it may be caused by several parts performing at marginal levels. Do some visuals first. Did you get all the air out of the system after the flush and fill? If it is equipped with a clutch fan, you should feel resistance while spinning the fan by hand (engine off of course) when the engine is warm. Is the fan shroud in place? Check the radiator paying particular attention to how the fins attach to the tubes. All the cooling fins should in direct contact with the tubes. The tubes are the vertical or horizontal lines between the zig-zag rows of fins.